# when app is run on phone (installed from bin folder's .apk file), grey tiled screen is displayed

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I installed apk on my android phone using the apk from bin folder, when i run the app on eclipse(phone is connected) it runs on phone but only grey tiles are displayed. wht to do?

MainActivity.java

```
   package com.example.lbs;

      import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.app.Activity;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

      public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

 }
```

LBS manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.lbs"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"    />    
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lbs.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="AIzaSyCROYDMk81v3LCsQShUnMjnezyshJAvJdY"/>

  </application>

  <permission
    android:name="com.example.lbs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission          android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>"
 </manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyCROYDMk81v3LCsQShUnMjnezyshJAvJdY"  /> 


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...so i had made the following mistakes:

1) I had used Mapview, which I then Changed to fragment view. Thanx to @Gabe Sechan for informing that

an example is [Simple android program using GOOGLE MAP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418753/simple-android-program-using-google-map-api)

2)When i was importing google play services, I didnt import it into my workspace, which led to error

to fix such error:- [Google Maps Can't add reference to Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124951/google-maps-cant-add-reference-to-play-services)

Best Link for newbies using google maps api v2: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 1):

What certificate was used to sign the APK? Make sure you've added the fingerprint for your debug certificate as well as your release certificate when generating your API key. See more instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: I havn't exported the project.....i've just copied .apk from bin & installed on my phone.....nw if i use fragment, won't it work? is adding fingerprint compulsury?

Comment: v2 does NOT require map fragment.  If you want to use a fragment, its available.  But v2 is perfectly fine with map view.  Really you should only be using fragments if your app needs them.

Comment: got this from LogCat....Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public