# Google Maps Can't add reference to Play Services

Tags: android, google-maps

I am attaching snapshot of the error I get and also snapshots of what I have done.

I have been trying for last two days, but keep getting the same error. Whenever I add a reference I get this.
[image]

The Android Dependencies.

[image]

Here is the Build Path

[image]

Comment: do you see google play services in your project under android dependencies and/or android private libraries?

Comment: I have added a snapshot to my question with Dependencies

Comment: you sure you added reference to it in the right project? what does your build path look like? `right click on the project click build path/configure build path`. do you see any errors there? also what does your `android private libraries` look like do you see it in there?

Comment: Post snap of `Java Build Path` section.

Comment: I have posted a snapshot of the Build Path

Comment: does not look like you imported it properly since it does not appear anywhere in your project

Comment: I have found a solution. Thanks for the help I couldn't of done it without you, thanks to your help I founfd out that it has not been added to my project. I will post the answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I was making is shown in the snapshot. Make sure `'Is Library'` is NOT Checked and that `'Android APIs'` is checked,

Also make sure the Project `'google-play-services_lib'` is imported and opened!
[image]

Comment: Well it worked for me that is why I posted this answer, as I was stuck, I thought it might help someone.

Comment: @MaciejGórski if you have a solution please share.