# .android google map show blank grid with zoom options

Tags: java, android

i m trying to add google maps to the android app.. although it only shows blank grid.. i m new at it if anyone can help
here's the code...

Main.java

```
public class Main extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);
    view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

Manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.rakesh.mapsg.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/themap" 
    android:clickable= "true"
    android:apiKey="my key"
  />
```

i m testing this on the phone only

Comment: You are using map api v1 use api v2

Comment: ` android:apiKey="my key"` will be the wrong key

Comment: Go for the Map V2 API

Comment: and how to use apiv2??

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Map Api V2, The important changes that you will have to make is

1) Make use of

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="android.app.DialogFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

i.e You have to use fragment tag in activity_main.xml instead of the mapview tag.

2) You should Specify the Google Map Api key in manifest.xml, instead of specifying in activity_main.xml as you have done above.

Refer This example:--- [Simple android program using GOOGLE MAP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418753/simple-android-program-using-google-map-api)

one more imp Step

3) Refer Google play services.....

example: [Google Maps Can't add reference to Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124951/google-maps-cant-add-reference-to-play-services)