# Simple android program using GOOGLE MAP API

Tags: java, android, google-maps

### Trying to work on Google Map's

- Its my first program in using google Map API
- I am not able to execute because of log error
- Where i need to correct myself

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="android.app.DialogFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.example.googlemaps.API_KEY"
            android:value="------------My-Key----------------" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

**UPDATED_XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPATED-LOG**

```
10-17 10:57:50.547: I/dalvikvm(458): Could not find method com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity.getFragmentManager, referenced from method com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity.initilizeMap
10-17 10:57:50.547: W/dalvikvm(458): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4829: Lcom/example/googlemaps/MainActivity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
10-17 10:57:50.547: D/dalvikvm(458): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
10-17 10:57:50.547: D/dalvikvm(458): VFY: dead code 0x0007-0028 in Lcom/example/googlemaps/MainActivity;.initilizeMap ()V
10-17 10:57:50.627: D/AndroidRuntime(458): Shutting down VM
10-17 10:57:50.627: W/dalvikvm(458): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemaps/com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  ... 11 more
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.googlemaps-2.apk]
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
10-17 10:57:50.657: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  ... 20 more
```

### Any IDeas

**Thanks**

Comment: In your xml change `android:name` to `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`

Comment: i made the changes .... still i have the error ... please look at the updated question

Comment: SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap = fm.getMap();googleMap = fm.getMap();

Comment: Use SupportMapFragment instead of using MapFragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare fragment class of map in your xml layout as below: Which is used to load the `GoogleMap` in your fragment.

Have your referred [Add a Map in your Application](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map) ?

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**EDITED:**

The error is because your application contains the API level below 12 . And  Please note that the code below is only useful for testing your settings in an application targeting Android API 12 or later, Below code should not be used in a production application.

```
      googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

So instead try as below:

```
   mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

Comment: Same way in your xml layout you have to define name as `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Comment: One more thing are Google MAP API is supported only after API level 12 & above ?

Comment: Yes, But its compatibility version is also provided.

Comment: If my answer helped you then please mark is as correct. @smriti2

Comment: I was not knowing that only one answer can be marked correct .... hey thanks for the help .... u always help me in stackoverflow :)

Comment: Glad to help you always . :)

Answer (score 0):

Just follow The Links As its your first map application.

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/developing-with-google-maps-v2-android
Follow the link and check 
1)make Sure U have google map v2 support library (Add android-support-v4) and

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

2)Check and modify the Manifest 
3) In layout

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/crntlocation"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

4)  In Activity

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap = fm.getMap();
```

It will solve your Problem.

Comment: Use In Manifest:<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Your Api Key"/>

Comment: Very useful information ... thanks ! [+1] upvote ...on my behalf ..... Still i am getting a error on emulator .... i post a new question on that ... thanks for leeting me know how to work with lover API12 devices

Comment: Are U getting error related to playstore.. Just Run Your application in Real device Not In Emulator.

Comment: Exactly ... i got the error .... is it not possible to run in emulator ? ...... is there no way i can test maps in emulator ?

Comment: Follow This Link And Run YOUR Map App In Emulator : http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/